# ¿Por qué cuando coloco este SELECT en una función deja de funcionar en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, funciones, phpmyadmin, funcion

Hola a todos estoy generando una función que devuelve un importe la cual es la siguiente

```
SELECT sum(Importe) from DetNomina where Clave IN (SELECT Clave FROM PerDedApo WHERE tipoPDA=0) AND CvePersonal=480 AND CveNomina='202211 10094'
```

Cuando ejecuto la función como consulta funciona perfecto:
Pero al momento de que coloco la consulta en una función no me arroja el mismo resultado, lo he intentado de dos maneras

```
SELECT sum(Importe) into variable from DetNomina where Clave IN (SELECT Clave FROM PerDedApo WHERE tipoPDA=0) AND (CvePersonal=480 AND CveNomina='202211 10094');
```

En ambos casos quiero asignar el resultado a 'variable'

```
SET variable = (SELECT sum(Importe) from DetNomina where Clave IN (SELECT Clave FROM PerDedApo WHERE tipoPDA=0)
```

Cuando llamo a la función no me da el mismo resultado, solo toma en cuenta esta parte de la consulta

```
SELECT sum(Importe) from DetNomina where Clave IN (SELECT Clave FROM PerDedApo WHERE tipoPDA=0)
```

Espero haberme dado a entender, de antemano Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Sería posible obtener la estructura de las tablas y algunos datos de prueba?. Aquí un ejemplo muy sencillo, ver [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fc182d7e2bac18b4963aaa43ee958f5d).

Answer (score 0):

Según https://dev.mysql.com/ MYSQL SERVER no acepta directamente esa sentencia que quieres hacer, mi consejo es que lo trates de hacer en un procedimiento almacenado, a veces tirar el sql directo en la parte de consultas en phpmyadmin puede no funcionar muy bien, más con sentencias tan grandes.

Espero que te ayude